# my transaction is not rollback when something goes wrong in C# with mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions, mysql-connector

I am connecting mysql 5.1 from C# by using mysql connector6.2.3.0(.net).I want to insert 3 tables at a time.So, i am using transaction for that.Suppose, when some errors encountered while inserting data into my 3rd table, then the transaction is not rollback.The data is inserted into first two tables.

This is my code...

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
 DBUtil cUtil = new DBUtil();
 MySqlConnection mysqlCon=null;
 MySqlTransaction txn = null;

try
{
    mysqlCon = cUtil.getDbConnection();
    txn = mysqlCon.BeginTransaction();

    //1 
    sql = "insert into test_details()";
    da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlCon,txn);
    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //2
    sql = "insert into task_details()";
    da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlCon,txn);
    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sql = "select task_id from task_details where test_id='" + testId + "'";
    da.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlCon,txn);
    dt1 = new System.Data.DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt1);
    string task_id = dt1.Rows[0]["task_id"].ToString();

    //3
    sql = "insert into test_evaluators()";
    da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlCon,txn);
    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    txn.Commit();
    mysqlCon.Close();
    da.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    txn.Rollback();
    mysqlCon.Close();
}
```

i think, initially, i want to disable autocommit... but i dont know where i have to set this...

please suggest me what's going wrong with this...

Comment: What format does your Mysql database have?

Comment: @DavidGoshadze : sorry format means?

Comment: This is excrept from Docs: 'In MySQL, only InnoDB and BDB (BerkeleyDB) table formats support transactions. Other standard storage engines ignore transactions and can not rollback data modifications.'

Comment: Btw imo you don't use InsertCommand in a right way. Try using ''MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlCon,txn); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); '' - this is a standard way of executiong commands. da.InsertCommand is used when linking DataSet to Database

Comment: @DavidGoshadze : Thanks a lot.could you please tell me "how do i know about it?" i am new to mysql

Comment: Did you install Mysql by yourself? With default installation it is probably InnoDb format. But read my prev comment

Comment: @DavidGoshadze : am checking now

Comment: @DavidGoshadze : I tried, but it was not rollback.do i need to set autocommit to false

Comment: You can chack table format with te command 'SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename' from mysql console

Comment: @DavidGoshadze : I think my table format is "MyISAM".Is this format support transaction?

Comment: No. Only InnoDB and Berkley

Comment: @DavidGoshadze :Shall i change it through phpmyadmin interface?

Comment: Yes, you have to, ifyou want to use transactions. See answer.

Comment: @DavidGoshadze : am checking now david...

Comment: @DavidGoshadze : Thanks a lot David... It working very fin... I will yours as answer for me...once again thanks a lot for following me  to guide... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we found out that it is DB engine problem, you can use

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE = innodb
```

refer [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-setting.html)